# Install4J, db configuration and Maven filters

Tags: install4j

I currently want to try Install4J to package up / install my Swing application.  I would like to know if it has a screen during installation where a user can input DB parameters (url, port, user, pass).  If so, I would like to know how this will work in the context of a maven build.  My Swing project is being handled by Maven and includes profiles to populate a db-config file using filters.  When a Maven build is completed, the jar file already has the db-config populated with the appropriate parameters from the filter in it's classpath.  All of this is packaged into an executable JAR file (with all dependencies included-- Spring, Hibernate, etc).

Now can Install4J use this big executable JAR file as is, "open" it up and insert/override the db-config file during installation with user-inputted values?  Or will Install4J need for me to use the basic jar file, add all jar dependencies (Spring, Hibernate, etc) separately, add the db-config outside of the jar, etc?

Answer (score 0):

1) Building a form that asks for your DB parameters is straight-forward, see [here](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/formScreens.html).

2) To modify a JAR file during the installation you can add the following sequence of actions:

- "Extract a ZIP file" action
- "Modify text files with regular expressions" or "Replace installer variables in text files" action if you put in the template values in the form ${installer:myDbParam}
- "Create a ZIP file" action

However, I would consider leaving such a configuration file outside the JAR file, it makes things easier.

Comment: The project is completely mavenized.  All dependencies are pulled from the repo and packaged into the resultant jar.  Can install4j hook into maven to grab the corresponding dependencies or must I grab each dependent jar and put them altogether for install4j?  Also the DB config file is located in the classpath (per Spring recommendation).  So when creating the final jar, this config file will be contained in that jar.

Comment: install4j has no maven-awareness. But you could just let the installer extract the jar file that contains the property file with your database properties.

Comment: The link to the page for the DB Parameters doesn't show a button or a way to "test db connection" when a user inputs the parameters.    So I would like to have a screen where the user inputs the db url, port, etc.  There will be a button to "test db connection".  If it passes, the "next" button will be enabled to continue.  Else it will always be disabled. Can that be done through install4j?

Comment: It can be done but you have to program the logic yourself. There is no "Test a DB connection" screen, just the elements which allow you to program such a screen.

Comment: Is there an example of this-- especially the programming part-- I can see?

Comment: There are sample projects in the "samples" directory in your install4j installation directory.